# Authorization for rest api in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, authorization

I have a RESTful web service in spring mvc. It has Preauthentication from external application. I have to implement authorization for the REST apis available. We have several vendors who consume these apis and based on vendor id i have to allow access to these apis. These access permissions should be configurable by admin user. Is there any suitable framework i can use for such scenario. If not is there any approach to solve this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably have a look on [Spring Security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#authorization). You should be able to find a lot of turn-key examples for authentication and authorization for RESTful endpoints. This would be one of the many: [spring-security example for authorization of REST urls](https://github.com/srinivas1918/spring-rest-security). And one more easy-going resource may be helpful to start with: [Spring Security for a REST API](http://www.baeldung.com/securing-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-security)